# How to integrate Telerik Reporting into ASP.NET Zero template?

Tags: asp.net-core, telerik, integration, aspnetboilerplate, telerik-reporting

Recently i am developing a project using asp.net zero template with boilerplate but  now i want to create some reports as per client requirement. For that reason i want to integrate telerik reporing with zero template but i can not create this. Please help someone and thanks in advance.

I already used Telerik.Reporting.Trial from Nuget package.

Comment: It is against ASP.NET Zero's license terms to cut-and-paste code like that. Besides, you didn't change anything.

Comment: Ask on [ASP.NET Zero support forum](https://support.aspnetzero.com/QA/Questions).